# UI flicker while pressing back in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am creating a UI for my company which has a edit-text at top and a frame layout at bottom. this frame-layout contains a mic image and animation on pressing of which it goes through 3 main state like listening.thinking and idle state. 
 So in short, user can provide query either by typing in edit text or by providing command by voice.
 My problem occurs when user click on edit-text to provide text command. When user do so the android keyboard comes up and user insert text but after entering text if user  press back button the ,the whole UI comes up before going down. This all happens very quickly and to a user it gives bad impression. It feels like UI is getting stuck but this is how by default android is handling it.
Is there a way by which I can stop this flickering or make this move smoothly.?

Currently I am making this frame layout invisible when user start editing and visible  when user has finished editing but this also does not help.

I know by not providing complete code it is not a good way of asking a doubt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    style="@style/main_style_mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog"
        style="@style/main_style_dialog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ScrollView
                >

                <!--will dynamically add here widgets and edit text button as required>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    style="@style/main_style_scrollViewlinearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainControlLL"
        style="@style/main_style_mainControlLL"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > // Act as parent container for mic image and text view

        <FrameLayout> //contains text view which gets displayed on top of mic image

            <TextView/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mic_btn_layout"
            style="@style/main_style_mic_btn_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="118dp" >// contains mic images

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipChildren="false" >// contains mic image for listening state

                <ImageView/>            
                <ImageButton />
                <ImageButton/>
                <ImageView />

            </FrameLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|center" >//contain mic images for thinking state
                <ImageButton />
                <ImageButton />

                <ImageView />
            </RelativeLayout>

          <ImageButton />//contains mic image for idle state
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in my manifest I have

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" and
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|locale"
```

Please let me know how i can correct my UI behavior.

Comment: Anyone has any idea about how to do it?

Comment: Are you doing something in `onConfigurationChanged`? Is `adjustResize` working as expected? (i.e. Your layout is fitted into the remaining space after the keyboard is shown) Also without positions and widths/heights in the layout, I am not able to reproduce your case. Can you post a layout which has all the positioning/sizes and also contains a set of typically shown (dynamically added) widgets?

Comment: I have getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); in onCreate . If i remove this UI does not flicker but the framelayout which contains mic part come above keyboard.  And I need full screen.

Comment: In onConfigurationChanged I initialize mic buttons and set the visibility of framelayout(which contains mic images) as visible.

Comment: take a look at this [link](http://www.thekirankumar.com/blog/2013/02/10/show-and-hide-android-notification-bar-without-causing-a-layout-jerk/) hope it helps

Comment: I tried that, flickering is gone but now window does not resize after tapping edit text due to which I m not able to see text I am entering. in short it is behaving as adjustNothing even though I have mentioned adjustResize.

Comment: Have you tried adjustPan?

Comment: tried . did not help .

Comment: can someone tell me why it is going up before coming down?

Comment: @AnujKumarJha can you provide a complete layout for me, which is conceptually equivalent to yours and has the flickering issue. I've tried to reproduce the error with your layout - by setting the missing attributes - but did not have any luck with that. My best guess however is that you provide **conflicting** settings: `adjustResize` means that ,,The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.'' and this might conflict with `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`.

Comment: Use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNone" in your manifest. It will not modify the layout when opening or closing the soft keypad.

Comment: Your activity is restarted on configuration change. Did you call the super.onConfigurationChanged() in your onConfigurationChanged?

Comment: Dont flag the activity fullscreen dynamicaly: do it in your manifest     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: One more thing i would like to clear is that i have customized the edit text class.

Comment: would just like to add a side-note. when you want to place a comment inside your xml code, you should place
`<!-- comment here --!>` instead of `//comment here

Comment: @RaviVadera  I trie dthat but in that case when my eidt text is last view i.e. it is in bottom and then if i want to edit it will not be shown.

Comment: Thanks everyone the issue got resolved.It was happening because I have overriden onKeyPreIme() API of Edit Text class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is API which I have modified to stop flickering.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        this.clearFocus();
        //Fix- Ui Flicker
       //  this.setFocusable(false);
       // this.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);          
        return false;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

In above API I commented the piece of code shown above.
 But Can some one explain why it was causing the jumping(going up) of UI. It was only disabling the focus of view.

Comment: Though it has resolved my issue but I do not know the reason why it was happening. Can someone explain it. ?

Answer (score 1):

You should put your activity state on a stack, since you are using fragments(more on this [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html)) and override the `onBackPressed()` function and restore your fragment state there.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // restore fragment/activity state here
     super.onBackPressed();  
}
```